# execute once a day per user until expire

Tags: mysql, sql, session, caching, asp-classic

I have a system with a subscription method. A user will get notified that his subscription is about to run out 3 days in advance.

The message works, but every time a user presses OK, and browse, a new sql insert will be sent.

What I want is that the user gets the message only ONCE a day.

```
Dim themsg = "Your subscription is about to end bla bla"
Set almost = ObjConn.execute("Select * from users where expire <= '"& DateAdd("d", -3, Date()) &"'")
If almost.eof then
Response.write "No users about to finish"
Else
dim sql
sql = "insert into events(uid, event, msg, sended, need_confirm, eventtime)"
sql = sql & " VALUES "
sql = sql & "('"& almost("id") &"', "
sql = sql & "'send_msg', "
sql = sql & "'"& themsg &"', "
sql = sql & "'1', "
sql = sql & "'1', "
sql = sql & "'"& Now() &"')"
on error resume next
ObjConn.execute sql,recaffected
End if
```

So as you can see everytime you enter this page, a new insert will be sent. Can I restrict it so it only send to this uid/user only ONCE a day, until the expiry date?

Comment: declare a variable and initialize to 1 = You can wrape insert code with in if statement and check if variable == 1 then alow to insert and after insert increment it to +1  ..and initialize to this variable 1 after date is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jradich1234 gave me idea on how to do it

added new column in events ´checkday´

Then added

```
Set kollar = ObjConn.execute ("Select * from events where uid='"& slut("id") &"' AND checkday='"& Date() &"'")
If kollar.eof Then

<<THE SQL INSERTION HERE >>

Else

Response.write "Already sent"

End if
```

So with this it check if the row with same ID & todays date found, if not insert.

Answer (score 0):

Add the what ever your unique identifier from your users table to the events table.  That way you can do a quick SELECT from the events table for user and eventtime to determine if an INSERT should occur.